# Keras get_weights takes longer to compute each time when looping

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to train keras models with a genetic algorithm, so for each generation I generate 100 random models to use parts of as mutations to the population. When merging and mutating I do the processing directly with the weights as numpy arrays, but I've noticed that when using the get_weights function it takes longer for each time I run it even though I'm getting weights from the same size model each time. I simplified my code to show this behavior below:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(
        input_dim=12,
        output_dim=8))

    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=4))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    return model

while True:    
    model = build_model()
    start_time = time.time()
    mut1 = np.array(model.layers[0].get_weights())
    mut2 = np.array(model.layers[1].get_weights())
    print(time.time() - start_time)
    del(mut1)    ##
    del(mut2)    ## Added these to rule-out a memory issue
    del(model)   ##
```

The behavior becomes clear after the first 50 or so iterations. I've tried debugging in pycharm but at least looking at the variables list there isn't a rouge variable that keeps getting bigger or isn't getting deleted, everything looks how I'd expect it to. Any ideas why the computation time is continuously increasing?

One more thing to note, I have timed the build_model() function similarly and it takes a constant 0.07s on my computer so I don't think that's a source of issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Keras stores session information behind the scenes, if anyone has more information on this please provide a more in-depth answer in case someone runs into an issue like mine in the future. Until then, I found simply adding

```
    keras.backend.clear_session()
```

between each loop solves the problem.